# In a right scalene triangle, can the other two angles be distinctly classified?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle, pythagorean-triples

How do I refer to each vertex of a right triangle by its angle property. I know the common angle classifications: acute, right, obtuse, straight and reflex. But what about a right scalene triangle, which has one angle $<45^\mathrm{o}$ and another between $45^\mathrm{o}$ and $90^\mathrm{o}$? I would like to have names for these angle types also.

I could refer to these verbosely, as "the vertex at the *short* (or *long*) edge of the triangle", but would prefer to use a vertex name. Though quite polysyllabic, I thought perhaps *semi-acute* and *semi-obtuse* (two *semi-right* angles for a right isosceles) but found no previous use of such terms. How would you distinguish these vertices?

For context, I am working with two pyramids which have a right scalene triangle base in common, and a peak that is orthogonal to an acute corner of the base. I wish to refer to each pyramid according to whether the peak is above the $<45^\mathrm{o}$ or $>45^\mathrm{o}$ base vertex.

Comment: You could call them the smaller/larger (acute) angles, or the vertices opposite the smaller/larger legs of the right triangle.

Comment: I'd give those vertices two labels, e.g. $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the humble $\space(3,4,5)\space$ triangle below. I always think of the legs $(A,B)$ of a Pythagorean triple as positive $(x,y)$ coordinates respectively. I also think of the angles as being adjacent and opposite, corresponding to the legs they are connected to. So, below, the
$\space53˚\space$ angle is the adjacent and the
$\space37˚\space$ angle is the opposite. This may not be a math standard but it is a convenient convention.
[image]